# Git Post-Update Hook - Can I handle "master" and "branches"?

Tags: git, github, hook

I have a post-update hook in a repo that looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
echo "**** Pulling changes into Live [Hub's post-update hook]"
echo

cd DIR || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull hub master
exec git-update-server-info
```

Is it possible for me to add conditions to this? I want to have it push to one directory if its a master `push` and another if its a branch that has been pushed?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is possible to get branch information based on what is passed to the post-update:

`BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $1)`